# Normal Coordinates for a Metric Ball Manifold With Boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Pardon if this is a well-known result as I am not an expert in this area.

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary. Does there exist a $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any point $p\in M$, the metric ball $B_\varepsilon(p)$ in $M$ is contained in a normal neighborhood of $p$?

This seems to be the case when there is no boundary, but I don't see how it generalizes to the case when $M$ has boundary and $p$ is close to the boundary.